# Reading GPS data from android device with Python

Tags: android, pydroid

I am trying to read data from an Android device with Python using Pydroid3.

I first tried the following:

```
import android, time
droid = android.Android()
droid.startLocating(0, 0)
event = droid.eventWait(1000).result
if event['name'] == "location":
  print(event['data']['gps'])
droid.stopLocating()
```

But this fails with:

```
Error importing module "android": this module is a part of Kivy
You cannot use it from elsewhere
```

Would be cool, if I could use it...

I then tried to use plyer to test an alternative:

```
from plyer import gps

def print_locations(**kwargs):
    print('lat: {lat}, lon: {lon}'.format(**kwargs))

gps.configure(on_location=print_locations)
gps.start()
# later
gps.stop()
```

And that fails with:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plyer.platforms.linux.gps'
```

I couldn't really find any resources that had similar issues...
Help is highly appreciated as I am a bit stuck here...

Thanks!

Comment: how are you executing python script? and how are you connecting to android device?

Comment: I have Pydroid 3 (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3&hl=de) as a Python IDE installed on my phone and execute the code locally on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

It's an older question, but for anyone still seeking an answer, here's how to achieve this for Android versions >= 12:

1. Launch the terminal in the Pydroid3 app.
2. If plyer is already installed, uninstall it:

```
pip uninstall plyer
```

3. Install the plyer fork from HyTurtle:

```
pip install https://github.com/HyTurtle/plyer/archive/master.zip
```

That's it!